# What is the longest URL I can subscribe to in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

Google calendar supports subscribing to ical files, where it will occasionally poll them for updates. This can either by selecting "Add Calendar > From URL" in Settings and giving a link to an ical file with protocols `http://`, `https://`, or `webcal://`, or by visiting the URL `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r?cid=webcal://«link»`. What is the longest URL that can be subscribed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The longest URL that can be subscribed to is 256 **UTF-16 code points**, including the protocol (e.g. `webcal://`). This translates to 256 bytes when using ASCII, but when attempting to pack as much data as possible in the URL, encoding techniques such as [base32768](https://github.com/qntm/base32768) can fit almost 500 bytes in a URL.

When adding a calendar URL longer than 256 UTF-16 code points, the "From URL" page in Settings just silently fails, and the `/r?cid=` url prompts the user to add the calendar, but just silently fails when clicking Add.